# How to limit the calculation in a sapply function?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, sapply

Several weeks ago I had a problem with calculating a coefficient in dependence to information from another data frame - [the link to the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284664/how-to-define-calculations-in-a-data-frame-depending-on-values-from-another-data). 
The solution provided by @PoGibas worked very well, however, I have to limit the calculation to only the 10 next values from data frame `A` after a defined time in each row. Could you please help me? 
My code looks as @PoGibas proposed:

```
sapply(1:length(time), function(x) sum(df1[x, which(foo >= time[x])]))
```

Comment: `sapply(1:length(time), function(x) sum(df1[x, which(foo >= time[x])][1:10], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: it works, thank you so much!

Comment: @jdobres Post that as an answer, so the question can be marked as solved :)

Comment: If you insist :)

Comment: Please, see also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47863732/3817004) to OP's last question which solves also this problem. (As my answer to the original question uses a  *non-equi join on reshaped data* it doesn't really fit to the question here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code modifies your existing code so that only the first 10 entries are selected and summed, if they exist. The `na.rm = TRUE` is needed for cases where there may be fewer than 10 entries. In such cases, R automatically fills the "empty" indices with `NA`.

```
sapply(1:length(time), function(x) sum(df1[x, which(foo >= time[x])][1:10], na.rm = TRUE))
```